# A program that's supposed to find out whether a number is prime or not isn't working as expected

Tags: python, primes

I'm trying to make a program which will find if a number is prime or not with a very simple formula: divide the number(x) by 4. see if any number from 1 to x/4 divides perfectly by x. If not, x will be prime.

The program currently shows me the result from dividing x by every number from 1 to x/4. I want to do this: If there's a number that divides perfectly, print that x is not prime and end the program. Or if there's no numbers that divide by x, just say that x is prime and end the program.

I tried using booleans but then it showed every number as prime, which it should not do since the program doesn't know yet that x can be perfectly divided by 1 but will still be prime.

```
value = int(input("Type a number: "))

# prime = True

if value.__class__ == int:
    x = value / 4
    list = list(range(1, int(x) + 1))
    for number in list:
        y = value / number

        while y >= 0:
            y -= 1
            if y == 0:
                print(f"{value} is not prime")
                # print("yes")
                # y == -1
            elif 0 < y < 1:
                print(f"{value} is prime")
                # print("no")
    # if prime:
    #     print(f"{value} is prime")
    # else:
    #     print(f"{value} is not prime")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, your description of your desired algorithm is not clear. You write "see if any number from 1 to x/4 divides perfectly by x. If not, x will be prime." But `x` will be larger than any of those numbers, so none of them will be perfect divided *by* `x`. Do you mean "divides perfectly *into* `x`"? If so, `1` divides perfectly into any number.  Finally, your apparent algorithm fails for `x=4` and `x=6` and `x=9`. Please clarify.

Comment: BTW: you should get rid of `if value.__class__ == int`. Firstly, you're already converting the input to an int. If it can't be converted to an int, you'll get a ValueError right there and will never get to the line in question. Secondly, this is not how you should check the class of an object. `isinstance(x, int)` would be one option, though there are a few different ones depending on what kind of behaviour you want in edge cases.

Comment: Setting `y = value / number` and decreasing `y` by 1 until it’s under 1, then checking if it’s 0 is a really slow way to write `if value % number == 0:`. (`%` gets the remainder of a division.)

Comment: @RoryDaulton You are right. it should've been the other way around. I was going to tackle the problem with 1 once I knew what was wrong with my current code. I don't know why it's acting differently with 4, 6 or 9. I want to know what exactly my program is doing behind the scenes but I'm kinda clueless about it.

Answer (score 0):

Your first logic is wrong. You need to check up to `math.sqrt(x)`

```
>>> import math
>>> [a/4 < math.sqrt(a) for a in range(100)]
[False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

This will technically work beyond `x=15` but then you'll be checking more numbers than you need to
You can see this by looking at the graphs https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dybweqs6lk

Answer (score 0):

first of all where did you find this formula?

second you didn't implement what you said in your code.
you need to check all four kinds that are possible after dividing and choose the result according to all of them, not in any loop.

Comment: I thought of this and I think I can also prove that it works. What are all the possible kinds? And I'm not sure which loop you're talking about. I'm totally new to coding, I hope you will help me.